# SQL Server 2005 to Mysql Replciation DATA duplication

Tags: sql-server-2005, mysql-replication, database-replication

I set up Replication between SQL Server 2005 and Mysql 5 using following articles :

http://ratecontrol.blogspot.com/2010/12/one-way-transactional-replication-from.html
and 
[error setting up replication from mssql to mysql](https://serverfault.com/questions/314598/error-setting-up-replication-from-mssql-to-mysql)

It works fine... but there is a problem that it sends all the rows from tables from my sql server 2005  publication to mysql . I just want it send the differences between the tables of publisher to the mysql subscriber. Please help ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Replication will by default send all the rows in the table.  SQL Replication won't merge the tables on the publisher and the subscriber.

Comment: Is that possible if SQL server only sends the rows which are updated or inserted for last period(which i have set) .

Comment: If you put a filter on the publication, and then did some editing of the stored procedures that replication creates on the subscriber you could probably get that working. Not sure if that'll work as expected when replicating to MySQL or not.  You might need to replicate to another SQL Server database first, then replicate that database to the MySQL server.